# webscraping data tables and data from a web page

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape real time streaming data tables and data from a web page
I tried:

```
library(XML)
webpage  <- "http://www.investing.com/indices/us-30"

tables <- readHTMLTable(webpage )
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))

tables
n.rows
```

but I get an error.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually proud of myself for getting this to work (I have been trying to get my head around these kinds of things for a long time now....)

```
library(rvest)
url4 <- "http://www.investing.com/indices/us-30-historical-data"

yourdata <- url4 %>% read_html() %>% 
html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="results_box"]/table[1]') %>% 
html_table()   

yourdata <- as.data.frame(yourdata)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I ticked that your answer was useful but how can I adjust the date so I get data back till say 2010? There is a calendar box to do this on the webpage.

Comment: also how can I webscrape the live streaming tables?