# Rvest Web scraping after selecting multiple historical dates in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to download the data from the HTML website https://wrldc.in/GeneratorScheduleChart.html#

I have been using the R package Rvest

I have seen some of the examples in StackOverflow from the link [request_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298886/rvest-webscraping-in-r-with-form-inputs).

While running this code I am getting error that
`Error: object 'request_POST' not found`

I am using selector gadget tools to get the HTML and CSS selector.

here we have another dropdown menu under 'Last Update at' header [image: Last Update at] that contains the data list @ 1-minute intervals.

What I want is to download the data after selecting calendar dates [image: Calendar dates/ datepicker] or date pickers and then get all the tables of all the list of 'last Updates at'

I do not like to use Rselenium package for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the correct endpoint dictated in the Javascript for the Ajax calls in the source html. If you then find the call to that endpoint, in the network tab, you can recreate the request with httr. You only need the Content-Type header but I would also add the User-Agent. In the body you pass the data.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

headers = c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Content-Type' = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
data = '{date:"2021-7-19"}'

r <- httr::POST(url = 'https://wrldc.in/GeneratorSchedule_data.aspx/Get_GeneratorScheduleData_state_Wise',
                httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data) %>% content()

df <- jsonlite::parse_json(r$d, simplifyVector = T)
```

Comment: Thanks. let me check from my end and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, @QHarr. I am able to get the data. But, here I am able to get the df of 'last updated at' time only. I want the df list of all the intervals time. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by all intervals? Do you mean for different days?

Comment: No, its Different time of each day. There may be 60×24 numbers of time intervals are available(check the dropdown. Dropdown menu of different time intervals are there. I have also upload image file names "Last Updated at" (present in my main questions). The header "Last update at" is having dropdown time intervals.  I want to download all the df.

Comment: Did you check the df? It has a range of time intervals.

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly. The results are as per my requirement.  > df_grp_id1 <- df %>% as_tibble()
> df_grp_id1 . Getting perfect outcome